# synchronize local Sqlite database with server database

Tags: android, database, delphi, synchronization, firedac

Server : retrieving data via TFDQuery, using MySQL

Client : store data in SqlLite, access via TFDTable/TFDQuery
(it's a one-way sync, called replication in this situation?) - meaning database is always most current in Server.

I've looked through a few threads on similar topics.

What's the best way to sync:
a) write custom code to go through each record (maybe calculate a checksum on a few critcal fields / all fields) - maybe via MD5 or CRC32.. ?

b) If the fields have the same name, is there an easy way to call FireDac functions/component so that all the local records which are different will be updated?

How best to reduce the traffic between client (iOS/Android) and server while checking the records for out of sync?  Or for every record, do I need a LASTUPDATED field so that I can compare what has changed?  Or any better way?

Sorry if I missed out on any threads that have already discussed this in detail while searching on this topic... probably wrong choice of key words.

Thanks for your pointers and advice.

Comment: Instead for checksum, CRC, MD5 or LASTUPDATED, I would use a simple "version number". That is an incrementing number store in each record being modified/updated/inserted. For deleted record, you have to use a secondary table to record what has been deleted. A client keep the last version number he got and to synchronize, request all records having a greater serial number.

Comment: Using timestamps is easier than version numbers because they can be automatically set by MySQL for inserted and updated records (either [like this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) or via triggers).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I suppose version number will use less storage space compared to checksum or timestamp.   Olivier, can't version numbers be automatically set via triggers etc too?

Comment: So for sync or rather replicating the database from server to client, is there some shortcut commands in FireDac, or I have to do manually to check each record for changes?

Comment: fpiette, just a thought. on client's side. the records would have differing 'version numbers' for each record.  on server side, it'll also be a table with records with different 'version numbers'... how then to request for all records having a greater serial number, let's say X.

Comment: *"can't version numbers be automatically set via triggers etc too"* Yes, but you would need to store the current version number in a separate table. So, every time a record is added or updated, the trigger would need to read the current number in that separate table and increment it, which means 2 extra queries. It adds some complexity and I see no benefit compared to timestamps.

Comment: *"is there some shortcut commands in FireDac"* No magical commands to perform replication.